# JMeter with Jenkins. Maven vs Command line execution

Tags: maven, jenkins, jmeter

I want to integrate in CI with Jenkins my performance tests in jmeter from a bitbucket (git) repo. I want to run them in a linux Jenkins slave.

I know that it's possible to do it through CL or Maven.

My question is... Pros and cons using command line or Maven?

In which case is neccesary Maven? It requieres more configuration?

Thanks in advance

Regards

Answer (score 0):

- Command-line mode is easier to configure, the only limitation is that you need to have JMeter installed on Jenkins [master and/or slave(s)](https://www.edureka.co/blog/jenkins-master-and-slave-architecture-a-complete-guide/)
- Maven is a little bit harder to configure and you need to have Maven installed on master and/or slaves, however [JMeter Maven plugin](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin) will automatically download JMeter

In both cases I would recommend considering adding [Performance Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-jenkins-performance-plugin/) to Jenkins, this way you will have ability to conditionally mark your builds as unstable or failed, performance trend charts, etc.

Comment: Thanks Dimitri. I´m wondering if I have a GIT repo where I upload my changes, including JMeter app folder... it will work in the same way like Maven each time I want to execute from a slave? I mean, If I set a git repository in Jenkins job and through command line I execute a test, I don't need Jmeter installed in master or slave because the entire project will be created in master/slave